# How to manage the nginx-ingress after installation?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I used this article as reference to install my ingress on azure's cloud. https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/aks/ingress-tls

But now I have some questions about it, how to manage that,like:
On this step I installed my nginx-ingress:

`helm install stable/nginx-ingress \
    --namespace ingress-basic \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set name=MY_RELEASE_NAME`

After that I had a LoadBalancer and a ClusterIP created and I must update manually my FQDN with the Public IP provided(azure provides)! e.g: 
`az network public-ip update --ids $PUBLICIPID --dns-name $DNSNAME`

Is there any risk of this controller be destroyed and I lose my public IP and then have to create everything manually again? 
If the answer is YES, how to do? Create a new job on azure to update it automatically? Does anyone know a sample of that?

Comment: question really makes no sense. if you deliberately delete the nginx ingress helm release - yes your public ip will be gone. one way of preventing that - not deleting the nginx ingress release or individual "resources" (kubernetes service).

Comment: Ok, the only way to lost that is if I deliberately delete the my nginx ingress helm release? that is my question, there is any other situation that I need pay attention? In other words, how I already said, Is there any risk of this controller be destroyed ?

Comment: Anyway, thank you @4c74356b41

Comment: no, there is no risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps

1. Create a public ip to be used as LoadBalancer Ip address using azure CLI. choose it as static ip
2. Create nginx YAML template using helm template command ( replace install with template in your command )
3. Update the nginx service type as LoadBalancer and update the LoadBalancer ip from step 1 in the template generated in step2 above
4. Deploy the helm template YAML

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried provisioning a static IP first? Then, using the official helm chart, you can use it like the following.

```
service.loadBalancerIP = YOUR_AZURE_STATIC_IP
```

Also, you may be interested in https://github.com/weaveworks/flux. It is a great tool to manage helm releases the GitOps way.

Comment: No, but I will do it now, use a static IP first! And thank you for the tip about flux, I will take a look on that Jhon.
Do you know the pros and cons about use static public IP or use a dynamic public IP on azure cloud?